# MigLayout, disable JButton width resize

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, miglayout

I have a button layout something like this

[image]

But the problem is *Text 1* and  *Text 2* is changing dynamically which screw up the whole button layout. For example, if the *Text 2* become longer than the buttons are resized soemthing like this

[image]

How can I prevent this and keep the button width same for both I am using MigLayout. Also any Text is not that much longer which can not be fit inside the button.

Answer (score 2):

Most likely, set your layout as `MigLayout("", "[grow, fill][grow, fill]", "[]")`

(Set both columns to grow and fill.)

However, if you post as [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), it'll be easier (for us) to test it.